# Dataflow profiles in Magento 2

Tags: magento, import, magento2

Does Magento 2 provides facility to import data using dataflow profiles as we do on 1.X ? I looked into latest Magento setup it only provides basic import and export. Is there any additional way to apply selected attribute import.

Answer (score -1):

you can import selected attribute by **System >> Import**  also ,

ex: updateproducts.csv

```
sku,manufacturer
DSLR-2310,Sony
```

[image]